# RAML different queryParameters, same resource

Tags: raml

I'm creating a RAML file where I would like to have 2 different `queryParameters` for the same `GET`. So 
`/userinfo`, for example, could be accessed by either set.

```
/userinfo:
    get:
       queryParameters:
           ...
       queryParameters:
           ...
```

Similarly, this doesn't work either:

```
/userinfo:
     get:
          queryParameters:
           ...
     get:
          queryParameters:
           ...
```

But, I get the error message below:

```
Error: method property already used.
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify a method (get, post, etc.) twice in the same resource. Nor the "queryParameters" keyword twice in the same method.

Parameters are just put one below the other.

For example:

```
/userinfo:
  get:
    queryParameters:
      one:
        type:        integer
        required:    false
        example:     1
      two:
        type:        string
        required:    false
        example:     "value"
      three:
```

More info [here](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#query-strings-and-query-parameters)

Comment: @thequestions did that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can not Define **Same** `Resource` *Twice*.
`/userInfo` is considered as a single resource, Defining again will give you errors.
In the mean time One can add multiple `queryParameters` Like Below.

```
/userinfo:
     get:
         queryParameters:
           id: number
           name: string
           type: string
```